# Discover joined rooms in agsxmpp

Tags: c#, .net, agsxmpp, muc

I am developing a chat application in `C#` and `.NET` with `agsxmpp`. So far I have managed to do *single chat* and *groupchat*.

But now I am facing a problem with retrieving the rooms which I have already joined as a owner or member.

I have tried finding on internet about such method, but there is no such. I know there is way of finding all rooms in sever. However I want to discover only rooms which I have created, i.e. I own or I am member of.

Is there any method in `agsxmpp` which allows this? or any other way to do it?

Any help is invited..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very good and I am facing it at the moment. The solution I found was to use the `MucManager` and request the list of **owners**, **admins** and **members** for each group.

The MucManager has series of methods that facilitate this. Here are some of them:

- `RequestMemberList(Jid, IqCB)`
- `RequestAdminList(Jid, IqCB)`
- `RequestOwnerList(Jid, IqCB)`

You need to make sure you properly define the iq call-back to process the lists when the server responds.

You can find more information on the `MucManager` class on the official documentation here: http://www.ag-software.net/download/xmpp/agsxmpp.7z

You need to download the source, unzip it and open the *html* based documentation in `../agsxmpp/doc/html/html/`

Comment: Thank you,for your help...i thought about this wayt earlier,but found it very lengthy,so now i have decided to use an API for this problem..

Comment: If your xmpp server provides a separate API that's good. What will happen however if you migrate to a pure Ejabberd? Your client implementation looses compatibility :)

Comment: Not sure way you found so lengthy, getting the group owners resulted in method 5 lines long for me. Maybe the problem you have is architecture related?